# display clob with all text formatting in itext

Tags: java, itext, clob

I want to display oracle clob data with all formatting in itext pdf.
currently i am using following code to display it.

```
java.sql.Clob clob=rs.getClob("MESSAGE");
Reader r = clob.getCharacterStream();
char clobVal[] = new char[(int) clob.length()];
r.read(clobVal);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
sw.write(clobVal);
//add some detail information about the country
doc.add(new Paragraph("Country Code: " + sw.toString(), bf12));
```

above code is showing only string but with no text formatting or html format data. kindly help.

Comment: What is inside your clob data? Can you give a sample?

Comment: I have html data in CLOB.

Comment: In that case you should use itext classes for html-to-pdf conversion. According to the tags of your answer I assume you use itext 5.5.x. Thus, you should use its `XMLWorker`.

Comment: And if you are using iText 7, use **pdfHTML**.

Comment: yes i am using itext 5.5 ... ok thank you so much i will use itext 7 and then i will inform you whether the problem is resolved or not ... thanks alot for reponse.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is binary data. CLOB is to store character data. Use BLOB and you will be able to get the formatted PDF.